# Attachments functions return "Error: attempt to apply non-function"

Tags: r, microsoft365

I'm trying to apply both $list_attachments() and $download_attachment() to my outlook object but they return the same error. The code is straight forward:

```
email <- my_outlook$list_emails(n = 1)

email2 <- email$list_attachments()
Error: attempt to apply non-function

email2 <- email$download_attachment()
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

Any ideas of what's going on?

Comment: What does `str(email)` show? Is it a list, NULL, or ...?

Comment: It's a list @user20650

Comment: okay. (by just looking at structure) I can reproduce errors with `em = list(a=1); em$fun()`. So you could try `email[[1]]$list_attachments()` (assuming that the structure of the list allows this / has just one level) . Otherwise, likely need a reproducible example, or t least more details on the objects structure.

Comment: It worked, just had to put the level in the statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user20650's comment I've identified the problem. It's the structure of the object, which is a list. The level needs to be stated so the function can work with the right element, like so:

```
email[[1]]$list_attachments()
```